# Scala Play: How to dynamically set response view per language?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've Scala Play 2.7.x and for views containing a lot of text instead of using the `MessagesApi` I simply segregate them by language like so:

```
/views 
   /en
     something.scala.html      
   /es
     something.scala.html
```

then in my Controller implementation I would do the following:

```
def doSomething() = Action { request =>
    val lang = request.lang
    lang.code match {
        case "en" => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.en.something()))
        case "es" => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.es.something()))
        case _ => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.en.something()))
    }
  }
}
```

But this is error prone and clearly not sustainable since I would need to recompile every time I support a new language. I'd rather prefer something like this (doesn't work):

```
def doSomething() = Action { request =>
    implicit val lang = request.lang
    val dynamicViewTarget = s"view.html.$lang.something()"
    Future.successful(Ok(dynamicViewTarget)) 
}
```

How can this be achieved? Maybe an even cleaner approach is to incorporate the `lang` as part of the routing resource and it goes to that view directly. Or a combination of these two ideas.

Comment: Does it really worth it? Can a language by added so frequently? I guess that anyway in such case some tests (QA, E2E, ...) would be required, and by the way cover that ...

Comment: @cchantep yep you got a point. I actually got the answer and it works but I am unsatisfied with the cost in ugliness i.e. reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I converged to the following complete solution. It's a module plugin that will resolve the Result target view dynamically (tested working on Scala 2.12.8 and Play 2.7.3):

```
package modules

import javax.inject.{ Inject, Provider, Singleton }
import play.api.Application
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.mvc.{ Result, Results }
import play.twirl.api.Html

/**
 * The dynamic template loader module implementation.
 * @param app the Play Application instance.
 */
@Singleton
class DynamicTemplateLoader @Inject() (app: Provider[Application]) {
  import Results._
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  /**
   * Returns the dynamically resolved play Result corresponding to a view function name using Reflection.
   *
   * @param target the target view name, note it's the name only e.g. "index"
   * @param args the formal arguments the view requires e.g. Seq(form, credentials)
   * @param implicitArgs the implicit arguments that the view requires e.g. Seq(request, messages, webJarsUtil,
   *                     assets, configuration)
   * @param langOpt the language to default to, if the language is defined then it will branch to the specific language
   *                otherwise will omit the language.
   * @return the dynamically resolved play Result corresponding to a view function name using Reflection.
   */
  def resolve(target: String, args: Seq[Any], implicitArgs: Seq[Any])(implicit langOpt: Option[Lang]): Result = {
    val loader = app.get().classloader
    val currentMirror = runtimeMirror(loader)
    val templateName = langOpt.map { lang => s"views.html.${lang.code}.$target" }.getOrElse(s"views.html.$target")
    val moduleMirror = currentMirror.reflectModule(currentMirror.staticModule(templateName))
    val methodSymbol = moduleMirror.symbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName("apply")).asMethod
    val instanceMirror = currentMirror.reflect(moduleMirror.instance)
    val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
    val allArgs = args ++ implicitArgs
    Ok(methodMirror.apply(allArgs: _*).asInstanceOf[Html])
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
def doSomething() = Action { request =>
  implicit val langOpt = Option(request.lang)
  val target = "something"
  val args = Seq(credentials) // e.g. user credentials
  val implicitArgs = Seq(request, messages, webJarsUtil, assets, configuration)
  Future.successful(dynamicTemplateLoader.resolve(target, args, implicitArgs)) 
}
```

and finally the sample `views/en/something.scala.html`

```
@import play.api.i18n.Messages
@import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
@import org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil
@import controllers.AssetsFinder
@import play.api.data._
@import play.api.Configuration

@(credentials: Credentials)(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, webJarsUtil: WebJarsUtil, assets: AssetsFinder, configuration: Configuration) {
  <div class="TODO">
  <div>
}
```